# refreshing php page with button

Tags: php, html

i have simple coding problem. i have created a page with textbox and share button. the page also contains one Points up button.

i had a problem with that points up button that when the user click on that button and **refresh the page** ... a window ask for **resend of information**

for that i have used following code which works fine.

`header('Location:  samepageurl.php');

exit;`

but the problem with above code is when user scroll down page and click the button. the page automatically scrolls up. and user have to manually scroll it down.

what i want is the page should refresh but it should be on the same location where it was.

if the problem is still unclear please refer the following images [image]

[image: after click on the button]

Comment: why do you want to refresh your page? its unusual to refresh your page if you are dealing with form... your inputted data will be lost after refresh unless if you want to submit your form and your data will appear after submitting.

Comment: i just want that button text should change to something else when user clicks on it ... thats the only reason i am refreshing it ... and yes i have coded it so that if user have already clicked it... the text will be " :) " instead if points up

Answer (score 5):

You can set a fragment identifier.

eg:

```
<a name="points_up"></a> <!-- this needs to be near that button, the page will scroll exactly where the element is -->
```

and redirect him to:

```
header('Location: samepageurl.php#points_up');
die;
```

Comment: actually every user post contains a points up button. i have edited the code shown above but its not working

Comment: @sumit you want to say that if you put `<a name="points_up"></a>` near the button and access the page with `#points_up` at the end it doesn't work ?

Answer (score 1):

Mihai answer is correct, but as you said that fragment identifier is not working because each user has points up button, you can pass `user id` as a fragment identifier and make a hidden(`display : none;`) `<a>` tag and pass the user id in front of each user...

Like this:

You can set a prefix before a **user id** too (optional)

```
<a name="pu12345" style="display: none;"></a>

<?php
   header('Location: whatever.php#pu12345');
   exit;
?>
```

Comment: Sir, can i have some kind of link there instead of that points up button

Comment: @sumit I don't know actually what's your point button doing, you can simply pass 1 more anchor tag with user id and make it hidden so that it's not visible on the page or better option is you can also add a fragment identifier and pass the username

Comment: @sumit you don't have to change it in your header, you need to change it near the point ups...

Answer (score 0):

You can send the request via ajax instead relying on the normal form submission.  That will not affect the scrolling of the current page.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line at the bottom of your page before the the <\body> tag

```
<button id="PageRefresh">Refresh a Page in jQuery</button>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         $('#PageRefresh').click(function() {
         location.reload();
         });
</script>
```